# Binomial theorem and it's geometric interpretation with functions

Tags: geometry, binomial-theorem

I know from the pictures below how to interpret the binomial theorem and it makes sense. But I can't make sense out of it if the equation I'm expanding with it is a function. For example if I have a function:

$f(x)=x^2 -2x+1$

Now if I want to find it's roots I equate it to zero and solve for x.

$0=x^2-2x+1$

I can do that using the binomial theorem for two dimensions.
$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$

The geometric interpretation is below.
Now using this the function becomes

$0=x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2$

And I know that it becomes zero if x=1 that's fine.
But what is the geometric interpretation of that in terms of the pictures below? You have a function, and not everything is constant, so you don't calculate the area of a square. What is the geometric interpretation that you can find the roots with it??

[image: Binomial Theorem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you describe is $f(a)=a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}$ when $a=x$ and $b=1$. Look at the picture below:

[image]

It shows that $(a-b)^{2}$ is the area of the light brown square. And it is equal to $a^{2}-b^{2}-2(a-b)b=a^{2}-b^{2}-2ab+2b^{2}=a^{2}-2ab+b^{2}$.

The closer $b$ to $a$, the more little $(a-b)^{2}$, the area of the square of side $(a-b)$. It is then natural that $(a-b)^{2}$ is equal to $0$ when $a=b$, because it is the area of a square of side $0$.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now how do you get a graph of a function out of this? The picture of the graph of the function doesn't link to this picture of squares in my head.

Comment: For some $b$ fixed, you will need a cartesian graph. $a$ will be seen on the $x$-axis and $(a-b)^{2}$ on the $y$-axis. If you do so, for a wide number of values for $a$ (with $b$ fixed), you'll get a parabola. Each point $(a,f(a))$ on your graph will be related to one picture of squares!
It is like $f(a)=a+b$. It is like beginning with a segment of lenght $a$ and adding it a fixed $b$. If you draw the graph, it will be a straight line for all $(a,a+b)$ possibilities.

Comment: That's interesting. I have to calculate a few example to see this. Thank you ;)